# React js: component is not unmounted properly

Tags: reactjs

We have following scenario:

```
1. Parent component has child components.
==============================================================
      <ContainerComponent>
         <Layout> 
            <CustomComponent>
               <ActualComponent>
            <CustomComponent>
               <ActualComponent>
==============================================================
```

This way component mounting takes place, and each ContainerComponent rendered according to task.

Component Container contain :

```
     return (
        <div className='row' >
          <div className='col-md-12' >
            <div className="ic-component" id="MainComponent"  >
              <div style={{'border':'5px;solid #e0e7f0'}}>
                <div id="rootwizard3" className='wizard'>
                  <ul>
                    {TabHeader}
                  </ul>

                  <div className="tab-content" id="tabcontent" >

                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
```

Then ContainerComponent contain Layout component :

```
   $("#tabcontent").empty();
    if(LayOut===null)
    { 
    }
    else {
      React.render(
        <div  id={tabid}><div  id={layoutid}>
          <LayOut CurrentStepId={CurrentStepId} TaskDetails={TaskDetails}  IsActualComponent="true"/>
        </div>
      </div>,document.getElementById('tabcontent'));
    }
  },
```

Layout component contains CustomComponent :

```
    var findDiv1=$("div > #"+TabbId+" > div > div > div > div > div")[0];
      $(findDiv1).empty();
    var valueP3=1;
      React.render(<CustomComponent inputType={Set} ItemName=""  ItemId=""  KeyValue={valueP3} addbtndispaly="" editbtndispaly="" deletebtndispaly="" Views="" />,findDiv1);
```

Unmounting of Container page:

```
  React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('tabcontent'));
```

Following way the components get mounted.

1. Initial component mounting. Here layout component loaded into Container Component. but custom component is not showing under Layout ? but output is poperly showing.
   [chrome react tool component loading structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uy8V.png)
2. Second time component mounting, but here it only remove component under "ctab137". not unmounting custom component . Second copy of cutom component get created.

   [chrome react tool component loading structure-Second time loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdHBz.png)

   2. When we go to task(functionality) it mounts parent component and accordingly
      respective child component gets mounted.
   3. When we click to another task mean containerComponent then only containerComponent unmount get called. for that we are clearing container componenet div where its child componenet get mounted. and load another task child componenet.

But here is we are facing problem when we mount child componenet every times it get mounted separately if that component is already present. and that create problem. Here is above mentioned custom component is not get propely unmounted. Every time separate customComponent copy is created and that times that funtionality get executed.

Also here is child componenets componentWillUnmount not get called.

I want to know answers of following questions .

1. How to unmount child components if it is not unmounted ?
2. How to call child components unmount method if it's not called ?
3. Is there any way to unmount component by component name ?